# python/pandas - would like to remove nested loops to improve run time

Tags: python, loops, pandas, indexing, vectorization

Given the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import *
from numpy import *

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df['A'] = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5]
df['B'] = ['a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c']

list_a = list(df['A'].unique())
list_b = list(df['B'].unique())
```

I would like to remove the following loops to speed up this next step...

```
for i in list_a:
    for j in list_b:
        df.ix[(df['A']==i) & (df['B']==j), 'C'] = i*j
```

Over tens of thousands of rows this is prohibitively slow. Thanks for any insight you many have.

*Pls note* - i*j is insignificant - I am pulling the other side of the = from a lookup table that would just complicate the example.

EDIT:  I believe this is an indexing question based on the items in list_a and list_b so that i may search in the ref table I mentioned previously and write into the filtered df['C']. Thanks again.

Comment: Would `df['C'] = df['B'] * df['A']` work? It gets you the the same answer you are currently getting and is much much faster

Comment: hi johnchase - sorry i wasn't clear. the point of the exercise is that i am using i and j to search in the lookup table i mentioned... so i think this is really an indexing question.

Comment: Describing your "lookup table" could help a lot. Is it another dataframe? Are you plugging `i` and `j` into a SQL query? etc. There may be a way to vectorize the lookup and speed this up dramatically.

Comment: Sure exp1orer - it's a dataframe with columns A, B and C  - and I need A and B to find C. However, that doesn't seem to be the bottleneck. Even when I set df.ix[(df['A']==i) & (df['B']==j), 'C'] equal to 1, it takes an impossibly long time to loop through my data set.

Comment: Right. My point is that depending on what is *actually* happening on the right side of that `=` sign, you may be able to avoid list_a and list_b altogether and operate on `df['A']` and `df['B']` directly, which would be faster.

Comment: fair enough. the other table (call it df2) is much bigger and not uniform for each entry in df['A'] and df['B']. i tried to simplify my question, but i am really trying to pull stock data out of a huge table and loop data into a pd.Panel() with: 1) items = various metrics, 2) major_axis = date, and 3) minor_axis = stock symbols. so the "df" in my example above is a single item in the panel i am trying to construct.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the details. I suggest you edit your question to include more details about `df2` and the panel you are trying to construct. I expect that the path to better performance involves manipulating `df2` and then operating on the columns of `df`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
df['C'] = df['B'] * df['A']
```

That will apply element by element operation of `*` for the matching pairs in `df['A']` and `df['B']`

Comment: hi sedavidw - before i saw your answer, i wrote to johnchase above "the point of the exercise is that i am using i and j to search in the lookup table i mentioned... so i think this is really an indexing question." sorry i was not clear in my question.